# Why a parameter is not defined, if I can dump it and it has a value in Coldfusion?

Tags: variables, coldfusion, parameters, defined

Just a little clueless... using Coldfusion8, if I dump my session to file:

```
<cfdump output="D:\ColdFusion8\logs\dump.txt" var="#Session#">
```

this includes:

```
accounttyp: whatever
```

I get the same result if I only dump this parameter:

```
<cfdump output="D:\ColdFusion8\logs\dump.txt" var="#Session.accounttyp#">
```

**Question:**
If it's defined and dump-able, how come checking **isDefined** like so:

```
<cfdump output="D:\ColdFusion8\logs\dump.txt" var="#IsDefined(Session.accounttyp)#">
```

turns out to be **NO**? If it's there it should be defined, shouldn't it?

Thanks for some clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `<cfdump output="D:\ColdFusion8\logs\dump.txt"
>   var="#IsDefined(Session.accounttyp)#">`

It is because the syntax is incorrect. `IsDefined` expects the *name* of a variable ie a string. By omitting the quotes around the variable name, the session variable gets evaluated first, and its *value* ("whatever") is what gets passed into `IsDefined`. So the code is actually checking for a variable named "whatever", not "session.accounttyp" ie:

```
    <cfif IsDefined("whatever")>
```

That is why the result is `NO`. This is the correct syntax. (Notice the quotes and lack of pound signs).

```
    <cfif IsDefined("Session.accounttyp")>
```

However, I would suggest switching to `structKeyExists`. It is generally preferred over `IsDefined` because it is more precise.

Answer (score 1):

This returns a boolean value:

```
#IsDefined(Session.accounttyp)#
```

So, you are asking it to return yes or no.

A better test might be this:

```
<cfif isDefined("Session.accounttyp")>
    <cfdump output="D:\ColdFusion8\logs\dump.txt" var="#Session.accounttyp#">
</cfif>
```