# How to check if an argument is received or defined?

Tags: coldfusion, cffunction

I have a function that has these arguments:

```
 <cffunction name="Agregar" access="public" returntype="any">
        <cfargument name="id_examen" type="numeric" required="yes" />
        <cfargument name="id_tema" type="numeric" required="yes" />
        <cfargument name="id_tipopregunta" type="numeric" required="yes" />
        <cfargument name="id_dificultad" type="numeric" required="yes" />
        <cfargument name="opciones_arreglo" type="array" required="no" />
```

I'm trying to use cfif to say what to do when the argument "opciones_arreglo" is not received. I used a function called `isDefined`, but it doesn't work. I just want to make the code run the else section, but I got this complaint about something that is obvious:

```
Element OPCIONES_ARREGLO is undefined in ARGUMENTS.


The error occurred in C:\www\htdocs\RHRR\componentes\bro\preguntas.cfc: line 24
22 :         <cfdump var="#Arguments#">
23 :         
24 :        **<cfif IsDefined(Arguments.opciones_arreglo)>**
25 :            
26 :             <cfinvoke method         = "RSAgregar"
```

Comment: You missed the quotes around the variable name: `IsDefined("Arguments.opciones_arreglo")`. Also consider `StructKeyExists(Arguments,"opciones_arreglo")`. Docs: [isDefined](http://cfdocs.org/isdefined) [StructKeyExists](http://cfdocs.org/structkeyexists)

Answer (score 5):

The problem were the quotes. Beginner mistake :(

```
<cfif IsDefined("Arguments.opciones_arreglo")>
```

Comment: Yep, [forgetting the quotes is a common gotcha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921081/why-a-parameter-is-not-defined-if-i-can-dump-it-and-it-has-a-value-in-coldfusio/10921421#10921421). However, I second Peter's suggestion of using `structKeyExists` instead. Primarily because it has greater precision than `isDefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add in a default value and it will always exist

```
<cfargument name="opciones_arreglo" type="array" required="no" default="#ArrayNew(1)#" />
```

Comment: Default values may or may not be appropriate for function arguments.  It depends on what's being done with the arguments and this question does not specify that.