# checking the existence while printing value in a table

Tags: coldfusion

I am displaying results in a table after looping through a query. For `TestNumber`, there are some results in my query where the number is not present and 
hence I want to display `N/A` instead of just blank in the table. So, I am checking the existence
using `IsDefined`, but for some reason it keeps on printing `N/A` everytime.

```
<cfloop query="GetMyList1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">#TestName#</td>
        <cfif IsDefined(TestNumber) >
            <td align="center">#TestNumber#</td>
        <cfelse>
            <td align="center">N/A</td>
        </cfif>
        <td align="center">#Date#</td>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to check if there is a length of the item. The field exists, so `isDefined` will always return true

```
<cfloop query="GetMyList1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">#GetMyList1.TestName#</td>
    <td align="center"><cfif len(trim(GetMyList1.TestNumber))>#GetMyList1.TestNumber#<cfelse>N/A</cfif></td>
    <td align="center">#GetMyList1.Date#</td>
  </tr>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thank you but you didn't use `isDefined` :)  Also, it is necessary to use `GetMyList1.TestNumber` instead of just using `TestNumber` as I am looping through the query `GetMyList1` ?

Comment: @user3558091 - `IsDefined` is the wrong function for what you were trying to achieve. Since `TestNumber` is query column, it will *always* be defined. Instead you should be checking its value or length. That said, the reason it always returned false, was that your syntax was incorrect. `IsDefined` [expects the *name* of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921081/why-a-parameter-is-not-defined-if-i-can-dump-it-and-it-has-a-value-in-coldfusio/10921421#10921421), but due to the lack of quotes, you were actually passing in the variable's "value" instead.